# Rails css/scss precedence

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I'm trying to figure out how the css precedence rules work in rails.

I have an app where I want to use different css rules for different controllers and if i add some css to one of the css.scss files, it affects all controller pages.

admin.css.scss:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}
```

rsv_ps.css.scss

```
body {
    background: url("DSC_1581.JPG") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='DSC_1581.JPG', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='DSC_1581.JPG', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

If i go to both `http://localhost:3000/admin` or `http://localhost:3000/rsvps/new`, they both have the background image.

Shouldn't any urls that start with `http://localhost:3000/admin` use the admin.css.scss stylesheet and not use the rsv_ps.css.scss stylesheet?

Comment: All of your CSS from the asset pipeline is included in all of the pages. The asset pipeline will serve all of your CSS assets as a single concatenated/minified file. You need more specific selectors.

Comment: Then what is the point of having separate css.scss files for each controller generated?

Comment: Better organization. Try applying a unique class to the body tag for each controller and styling against that.

Comment: If the body tag is in my layout, how would i specify a different class per controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments by @meagar and @catfish are correct. (not sure why they're not putting their answers in a post)

The separate pages are just for organization, they are not for keeping the css separate. The asset pipeline will combine and minimize the separate css files into one big file.

So you need to separate the styles yourself by using specific selectors.

Something like

```
# for admin
body.admin {

}

#html
<body class='admin'>


# for everything else
body.default {

}

#html
<body class='default'>
```

To specify the markup in your layout

```
<body class="<%= @admin ? 'admin' : 'default' %>">
```

Comment: Good to know. I was thinking that they rendered separately per controller. Thanks.

Comment: That `.admin { body { } }` isn't how you select a `body` element with class `admin`. It's `body.admin`.

Comment: Also, no need for a default class if the admin class is declared after  body, e.g. `body {...} body.admin {...}` (or nested at the bottom for .scss). This also doesn't specify how he sets the class since it's in his layout file.

Comment: @meagar thanks for the correction. I think I was mixing it up with the sass syntax.

Comment: @ColinR good points. Updated for the layout markup but kept the css classes explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove the line `*= require_tree .` and then manually setup the manifest to include the files you want to be compiled into `application.css` (You could also convert `application.css` to `application.css.scss` and use `@import`). This means you could then add specific stylesheets to each view by using the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper. *Note that you have to add the `.css/.scss` files you need compiled (not included in `application.css`) to `config/environments/production.rb`*

You could also just a use specific css class on the body for admin which would override the default body styling:

```
<body class='<%= 'admin' if @admin %>'>
```

and set `@admin` with a filter in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

`Rails assets pipeline` create a single `minified` version for all included `css` and add it to every page.

You need to use separate `selectors` for different pages.Otherwise there is one more option is to use `layout` to separate it but it's not good way to create multiple layouts just for differentiating `css` for every page.